# Why are these plots bunched together, instead of showing immediatly after the related dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a for loop to create some dataframes, and I want to make a histogram immediatly after a datafram is displayed.

```
places = [
    'place 1',
    'place 2',
    'place 3',
]

for place in places:
    print(place,":")
    result = properties[properties['Suburb'].str.contains(place)]
    display(result[:1])
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    plt.hist(result['Price'])
    plt.title(place)
```

I hope the result will be like this:

```
Place 1
Dataframe 1
plot 1

Place 2
Dataframe 2
plot 2

Place 3
Dataframe 3
plot 3
```

But instead, the plots are on their own, and shown after the dataframes have been displayed, like this:

```
Place 1
Dataframe 1
Place 2
Dataframe 2
Place 3
Dataframe 3
plot 1
plot 2
plot 3
```

[image: plots showing together after the dataframes]

Any suggestions why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Unless forced, matplotlib draws figures when control is returned to the user. In your example, this occurs after all code has finished evaluating, which is why the tables get drawn first, and only then the figures.

You can force a draw by appending

```
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```

to the end of your loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tho the code didn't work for me, yout answer helped me knowing that that I need to force it to show up. So I tried adding plt.show(), and it worked as I wanted.